# Calculating R squared from multiple columns

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm very new to R and have been trying to figure out how to calculate R^2 from a few columns within a large data set of approx 300+ columns.

Example:

```
rcalc <- data.frame('x1' = c(694, 702, 701), 'x2'=c(652, 659, 655),
 'x3'=c(614, 612, 613), 'y1'= c(17.97, 17.95, 17.96), 'y2' = c(12.03, 12.0,
 12.1), 'y3' = c(0.09, 0.1, 0.1))
```

From here I am stuck.

The formula in excel I can do, and looks like this:

> RSQ(X1:X3, Y1:Y3) *or RSQ(694:652:614, 17.97:12.03:0.09)*

So, each row needs to be calculated for R^2. I was able to use the 'lm' command but was only able to do this for 1 row:
I had to take the value from each column of x (x1:x3) and stack them into 1 column, then each value from each column y (y1:y3) and stack into 1 column. Then performed the following:

```
rsqrd = lm(x~y, data=rcalc)
summary(rsqrd)$r.squared
```

This worked but again, only for 1 row. I'm not sure how to do this for thousands of rows. I hope this wasn't too confusing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Troubleshooting:

with pivot_longer:

```
row col obs value
1   c   300_0 DUT Ip2_comp  784.9775
1   c   300_12 DUT Ip2_comp 864.4234
1   c   300_18 DUT Ip2_comp 919.3384
1   c   300_0 REF O2    0.09
1   c   300_12 REF O2   11.95
1   c   300_18 REF O2   17.98
2   c   300_0 DUT Ip2_comp  781.5785
2   c   300_12 DUT Ip2_comp 865.5541
2   c   300_18 DUT Ip2_comp 921.0646
2   c   300_0 REF O2    0.09
```

With Pivot_wider:

```
row obs c
1   300_0 DUT Ip2_comp  784.9775
1   300_12 DUT Ip2_comp 864.4234
1   300_18 DUT Ip2_comp 919.3384
1   300_0 REF O2    0.09
1   300_12 REF O2   11.95
1   300_18 REF O2   17.98
2   300_0 DUT Ip2_comp  781.5785
2   300_12 DUT Ip2_comp 865.5541
2   300_18 DUT Ip2_comp 921.0646
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be done more concisely, but here's one approach using tidyverse functions. First, I do some reshaping to add a row number and make it into a longer shape, with columns for row, observation # (1-3), x, and y.

Then I "nest" all the data except row number so that I can run a separate regression on each row's data, and then extract r squared (and a variety of other stats) from each regression.

```
library(tidyverse)


rcalc %>%  # your data

  # reshape to get matched columns for all x and for all y values
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = c("col", "obs"), names_sep = 1) %>%  # split column name into two fields after first character
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>% 

  # nest data, regression, unnest
  nest(-row) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, function(df) lm(y ~ x, data = df)),
         tidied = map(model, broom::glance)) %>%
  unnest(tidied)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 15
    row data             model  r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <int> <list>           <list>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1     1 <tibble [3 × 3]> <lm>       0.952         0.905  2.81      20.0   0.140     1  -5.71  17.4  14.7     7.91           1     3
2     2 <tibble [3 × 3]> <lm>       0.973         0.946  2.10      36.3   0.105     1  -4.84  15.7  13.0     4.43           1     3
3     3 <tibble [3 × 3]> <lm>       0.951         0.903  2.84      19.6   0.141     1  -5.74  17.5  14.8     8.05           1     3
```

---

Edit: for troubleshooting, I am adding here the results I see at each stage:

*after the pivot_longer step:*

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
     row col   obs    value
   <int> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1 x     1     694   
 2     1 x     2     652   
 3     1 x     3     614   
 4     1 y     1      18.0 
 5     1 y     2      12.0 
 6     1 y     3       0.09
 7     2 x     1     702   
 8     2 x     2     659   
 9     2 x     3     612   
10     2 y     1      18.0 
11     2 y     2      12   
12     2 y     3       0.1 
13     3 x     1     701   
14     3 x     2     655   
15     3 x     3     613   
16     3 y     1      18.0 
17     3 y     2      12.1 
18     3 y     3       0.1
```

*after the pivot_wider step:*

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
    row obs       x     y
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1       694 18.0 
2     1 2       652 12.0 
3     1 3       614  0.09
4     2 1       702 18.0 
5     2 2       659 12   
6     2 3       612  0.1 
7     3 1       701 18.0 
8     3 2       655 12.1 
9     3 3       613  0.1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Im confused on the 2nd part, Nest,regression,unnest. Do I replace "df" and "y ~ x" with my dataframe and column variables?

Comment: No, it should run as is, starting from your `rcalc`. Take a look at the output after the `pivot_longer` step (e.g. by removing the `%>%` pipe so the chain ends with that line). You'll see that the columns like `x1` and `y3` have been converted into a longer format, with one column `col` describing if it's x or y, and another column `obs` with the number of observation (like 1 or 3). The next pivot_wider line then converts those wide again so that x and y get their own columns. It's those `x` and `y` columns that are fed into the regression.

Comment: Oddly, I get an error every time that says "Problem with 'mutate()' input 'model'. x object 'y' not found i Input 'model' is 'map(data,function(df) lm(y ~ x, data = def))'.

Comment: I am using tidyverse 1.3.1 and it doesn't give me an error, perhaps you are using an older version with slightly different behavior? If you break the chain after the `pivot_wider` step, is there a `y` column?

Comment: Oh maybe that is it... When I break after pivot_wider, I have 3 columns: row, obs, c. Just checked and I am using version 1.3.0 for Tidyverse

Comment: Sounds like our pivot steps are not aligned. I've added my intermediate results to my answer, where does it start to vary with yours?

Comment: I also edited my question with updated info for troubleshooting. Thanks!

Comment: Aha. Does it work on the data you provided in the question? It looks like you are using it on different data that has different columns named something like `c300_0 DUT Ip2_comp`?  You will have to modify the `pivot_longer` step using `names_sep` or `names_pattern` to split out, presumably, the "DUT" and "REF" parts. It will probably be cleanest to use some regex for that, but a simpler solution might be to take the column names as-is (e.g. `pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "col") %>%` and then use `separate()` to extract the different elements into separate columns.